# несколько файлов в один исполняемый linux

Tags: linux, elf

У меня есть исполняемый файл, который далее обращается в папки и там запускает программы и тд
Как мне сделать так, чтобы все эти файлы превратились в один исполняемый файл?

Насколько я знаю, в винде можно все впихнуть все в .exe файл, чтобы конечный пользователь не видел все файлы.

А как такое провернуть в linux? Если возможно все впихнуть в elf файл, то как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970047/add-resources-to-elf-object-grouped-in-one-section

Comment: Я бы поэксперименторовал с упаковкой всего вашего хозяйства в .so (тоже ELF и вообще говоря вызывается (пробовал с /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so из bash и просто программы через `execve()`))

Comment: Вот, похоже, [рецепт](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223385/why-and-how-are-some-shared-libraries-runnable-as-though-they-are-executables), как их делать runable

Comment: [makeself - Make self-extractable archives on Unix](https://github.com/megastep/makeself)

Comment: Есть же shar или как оно там зовётся: shell archive. @avp

Comment: Посмотрите, как это делает busybox. Насколько я понимаю, он проверяет argv[0] и в зависимости от него выполняет то или иное.

Comment: @0andriy,  [shar](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/filearchiv.html) это самораспаковывающийся архив и ничего более. Нет возможности вызова его частей без распаковки. ТС же,  насколько я понял вопрос, хочет вызывать части одного файла.